# Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python - Django Visual Studio

Tags: python, django, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use firebase in my python django project.  This is on a windows machine using visual studio.  I get the error "Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python" when I try to import it:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

I have tried everything I can find through google including:

1. Manually installing grpcio
2. Downgrading protobuff to various versions.  This one actually just ends up with a different error depending on which version of protobuff I go with.
3. Uninstalling and re-installing google-cloud-store and all other dependencies
4. Re-installing and upgrading pip

And several other minor things over the course of the day that I can't recall.  I am at a dead end after a full day of bashing my head against this.  Any other solutions or even a direction to look in?

Here is installed packages list:

```
CacheControl             0.12.6
cachetools               4.1.1
certifi                  2020.6.20
cffi                     1.14.2
chardet                  3.0.4
defusedxml               0.6.0
diff-match-patch         20200713
Django                   2.2.16
django-import-export     2.3.0
docutils                 0.16
et-xmlfile               1.0.1
firebase-admin           4.3.0
google-api-core          1.22.2
google-api-python-client 1.12.1
google-auth              1.21.1
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.4
google-cloud-core        1.4.1
google-cloud-firestore   1.9.0
google-cloud-storage     1.31.0
google-crc32c            1.0.0
google-resumable-media   1.0.0
googleapis-common-protos 1.52.0
grpcio                   1.32.0
httplib2                 0.18.1
idna                     2.10
jdcal                    1.4.1
MarkupPy                 1.14
msgpack                  1.0.0
mysql-connector-python   8.0.21
odfpy                    1.4.1
openpyxl                 3.0.5
pip                      20.2.3
protobuf                 3.13.0
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pycparser                2.20
pytz                     2020.1
PyYAML                   5.3.1
requests                 2.24.0
rsa                      4.6
setuptools               50.3.0
six                      1.15.0
sqlparse                 0.3.1
stripe                   2.51.0
tablib                   2.0.0
uritemplate              3.0.1
urllib3                  1.25.10
xlrd                     1.2.0
xlwt                     1.3.0
```

Dunno if noteworthy, but when I try to do the imports like this as another post recommended:

```
import os
import firebase_admin
from google.cloud import firestore
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

I instead get "DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found." in descriptor.py for "rom google.protobuf.pyext import _message".  I dunno if its related at all but figured id included the info.

Comment: I did some research on the second error you shared, the DLL error, and found this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25072) for tensorflow, but the error message is the same so I figured it's worth a shot, in this issue it is stated that downgrading `protobuf` to version 3.6.0 fixed the issue, could you try that and let me know if it works?

Comment: If I follow that and downgrade protobuf to 3.6.0 I just get this error instead: "module 'google.protobuf.descriptor' has no attribute '_internal_create_key'"  To which the common solution is to update protobuf to a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to python 3.7.8 fixed this issue for me.